# Find multiple overlapping routes on Google maps

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2, overlap

I would like to use Google maps for Android to find whether given two routes overlap.

Currently I've used the Google maps API to get two locations from a user and draw the optimum driving route between the two locations. I have the json result from the API and hence I would be able to store the current path.
Imagining I have hundreds of these kind of pre-planned routes in a database for example, what would be the optimum way to check whether a given new routes overlaps with any stored path.
Following is a summary of the question.

[image: Test whether the new path overlaps with stored paths]

The simplest method that I can think of is to check every LatLng to find whether the two paths coincide with each other. But this would be an extremely costly approach.

In order to reduce the cost in this approach, I can find bounding boxes of each path and check whether the bounding box of the new path resides inside the bounding boxes of parent maps. This would reduce the cost, but still I would need to calculate each Latitude Longitude point to see whether they overlap with each other.

I've tried to find any API support on this yet failed up to this point. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for spending your valuable time to read this.

Comment: Hi, I think your approach for bounding box is good, and you should use it (maybe adding another check for the remaining features to check start and end point could help), but there is no "free" way to get two overlapping lines. Usually in GIS systems you use spatial database, but we don't have it in android (should explore spatialite). The point-by-point check is the only one as far as i know...

Comment: Pointing me towards spatial database was a key turn. Thank you very much. Didn't know that. Indeed I'm going to try on that